# How do I make JSON easier to read in my React-Typescript app?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, json, typescript

I have made the JBook app following Stephen Grider's [React and Typescript](https://www.udemy.com/course/react-and-typescript-build-a-portfolio-project/) course. I would like to make sure that the content of the user's local file has all their content written clearly in the JBook. Currently the content is all in JSON which isn't great when it comes to readability.

My `local-api/src/routes/cell.ts`:

```
import express from "express";
import fs from "fs/promises";
import path from "path";

interface Cell {
  id: "string";
  content: "string";
  type: "text" | "code";
}

interface LocalApiError {
  code: string;
}

export const createCellsRouter = (fileName: string, dir: string) => {
  const router = express.Router();
  router.use(express.json());
  const fullPath = path.join(dir, fileName);

  router.get("/cells", async (req, res) => {
    const isLocalApiError = (err: any): err is LocalApiError => {
      return typeof err.code === "string";
    };
    try {
      
      const result = await fs.readFile(fullPath, { encoding: "utf-8" });

      res.send(JSON.parse(result));
    } catch (err) {
      if (isLocalApiError(err)) {
        if (err.code === "ENOENT") {
        
          await fs.writeFile(fullPath, "[]", "utf-8");
          res.send([]);
        }
      } else {
        throw err;
      }
    }
  });

  router.post("/cells", async (req, res) => {
    const { cells }: { cells: Cell[] } = req.body;
    
    await fs.writeFile(fullPath, JSON.stringify(cells), "utf-8");
    res.send({ status: "ok" });
  });

  return router;
};
```

If I change the `router.post` to this:

```
router.post("/cells", async (req, res) => {
    const { cells }: { cells: Cell[] } = req.body;
    const formattedContent = cells
      .map((cell) => {
        if (cell.type === "text") {
     
          return `/* Text Cell: ${cell.id} */\n/* ${cell.content}*/`;
        } else {
    
          return `/* Code Cell: ${cell.id} */\n${cell.content}`;
        }
      })
      .join("\n\n");

    await fs.writeFile(fullPath, formattedContent, "utf-8");
    res.send({ status: "ok" });
  });
```

I guess I would need to write a custom paser to get this to work? If that's the case, I'm not sure where to start.

Or are there any libraries that might be useful?

Comment: What format do you propose using? Any format is going to need structure and that's what JSON gives you. I guess its not as nice because you have really long strings? What fields do you have in a "JBook"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question it is unclear if you want users to be able to provide the entries in this proposed format or if the existing entries stored in the DB should be able to be retrieved in this new format.

It's always best not to invent a new format. That just means your files are far harder to work with and actually, can make them *less* readable as now they won't work with known tooling meant to manipulate those formats. You want to lean on open standards. But there are possibly better ones than JSON for heavy text applications...

This sounds like you could use Markdown with [Front Matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/) as a format (used by many other products like Jekyll & Github).

Markdown is focused on displaying and formatting large blocks of text, but with the addition of Front Matter, these Markdown files (`.md`) can also specify a little preamble of structured data in YAML format.

You'd also get nice display using any Markdown reader (VSCode has one built in).

So an entry could look like this:

```
---
id: My example ID
type: text
---

I am the content for this entry!
```

Front Matter has lots of NPM libraries to both generate and parse this format like [gray-matter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gray-matter), [front-matter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/front-matter) but the most updated and supported one seems to be [mdast-util-from-markdown](https://github.com/syntax-tree/mdast-util-from-markdown) alongside [mdast-util-frontmatter](https://github.com/syntax-tree/mdast-util-frontmatter)
 for the front matter part.

It's worth noting it may still make sense to *store* the entries in JSON. If this was backed by a real database, you'd have to conform to its standards. But you could easily accept input in the markdown format and also provide endpoints to retrieve them in this format by translating between the 2 formats.